# Selecting following characters after a pattern match in R

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have a data frame which has one column of text with info that I need to extract, here is one observation from that column:  each question has three attributes associated to it objectives,KeyResults and responsible

```
[{"text":"Newideas.","translationKey":"new.question-4","id":4,"objectives":"Great","KeyResults":"Awesome","responsible":"myself"},{"text":"customer focus.","translationKey":"new.question-5","id":5,"objectives":"Goalset","KeyResults":"Amazing","responsible":"myself"}
```

-------------------------DESIRED OUTPUT -----------------------

```
Question#   Objectives KeyResults responsible Question#   Objectives KeyResults responsible 
4            Great      Awesome    myself       5           Goalset    Amazin     myself
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to shhow the example

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Data is a valid `json` (but you need square bracket closing `]` on it). You can read json into R object using json parser package (eg. `jsonlite`)

Let say your text is in column `text` of data frame `df`, then this will transform that text into R dataframe.

```
library(jsonlite)

dat <- fromJSON(df$text)
dat

#              text translationKey id objectives KeyResults responsible
# 1       Newideas. new.question-4  4      Great    Awesome      myself
# 2 customer focus. new.question-5  5    Goalset    Amazing      myself
```

You need to install `jsonlite` to make it works

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
```